# Matching regex for adb gfxinfo logs

Tags: regex

I am trying to grep the information from the adb dumpsys gfxinfo logs

The pattern i used is

```
\d+\s?(?=\()?
```

The string text may contain following information

```
Janky frames: 2 (100.00%)
```

or

```
Janky frames: 2
```

In both the cases i need the ouput as 2.

But the regex above used matches the 100 too.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/SOqRrY/2) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
\d+(?=\s*\()|\d+$
```

It matches a number which must be followed by optional whitespace character and an opening bracket (non-matching). It also matches a number at the end of the line.

Comment: You do not need to repeat `\d+`, use `\d+(?=\s*\(|$)`